# Solve $|\frac{dy}{dx}|+|y|+a=0$ for $a=0,a>0,a<0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation, $|\frac{dy}{dx}|+|y|+a=0$,
>   $a\in\mathbb{R}$. How to find the solution for the differential
>   equation for $a=0,a>0,a<0$?

I don't know how to start. I usually come across ODE does not contain mod sign. Please help me.

Comment: I bet you can solve the cases $a=0$ and $a>0$ fairly easily (or for the second show it does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Well, for $a >0$ there is no solution.
If $a=0$, you get $|\frac{dy}{dx}|+|y|=0$, which means $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and $y=0$. It's easy to solve this one ,right?
If $a<0$, you need to consider more cases: $$\begin{array}{l}
 \text{case 1: } \frac{dy}{dx}>0, y>0, \text{we get } \frac{dy}{dx}+y+a=0 \\
\text{case 2: } \frac{dy}{dx}<0, y>0, \text{we get } -\frac{dy}{dx}+y+a=0
\end{array}$$ and so forth. You need to make sure your solutions will satisfy conditions that where used to remove the absolute value bar.